# Codeigniter htaccess and xampp

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I user codeigniter in my web application programming and the last days i turn from appserv to xampp.

The problem is when the path contains two '/' the page return error: 404 Page Not Found

Like : http://domain.com/script//admin/

But when single '/' the page works right

Like: http://domain.com/script/admin/

The "http://domain.com/script" is the base_url in codeigniter config and the domain.com is localhost.

Note: This problem wasn't appear with appserv

Comment: can you post your .htaccess content

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ webapplication.php?/$1

Comment: Do you enable the mod_rewrite of xampp. check this link if not [http://www.leonardaustin.com/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp] . Another question : which version of CI are you using ?

Comment: Thanks, It works right with removing '/' after base_url

Answer (score 1):

CI's `base_url`already comes with a forward slash at the end (if left empty in the `config`file), so when you build links in views using `echo base_url();`, you don't need a second forward slash:

`<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin">Link</a>`

Comment: Thanks, I remove forward slash and it works but why this problem appears in xampp not in appserv ?

Comment: I've never worked with appserv, so I don't know. But in the config file `base_url` is defined as: "URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL, WITH a trailing slash"; so that is how `base_url`should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Double slash does not make any sense in URLs. But follwoing should work:

1. Check if `RewriteModule` is enabled in xampp in apache/httpd.conf

Also share the .htaccess of you CI project

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ webapplication.php?/$1

Comment: then if in xampp, rewrite module is enabled

Comment: and why are you using double slash? It does not make any sense. `base_url` returns you the /